# hover not working for all elements in list

Tags: html, css, hover

```css
  body{
  background: url("Mypic.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.btns12{
position: absolute;
width: 1200px;
margin-left:0px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 0px;
}
h1{
  color:gray;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 70px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-top: 450px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 250px;
}

.button{

  margin-left: 500px;
}

.btn{
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: pink;
 font-family: inherit;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.btn1:hover{
  background:white;
}
.btn2:hover{
    background:white;
}
.tabs{
float: right;
list-style: none;
margin-top: 30px;
}
.tabs li{
  display: inline-block;
}
.tabs li a{
  color: white;
  font-family: inherit;
   padding: 5px 30px;
   text-decoration: none;
   background: pink;
   height: 100%;
}
 .tabs li a:hover{
  border:1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Marwa's Services</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="menu">
    <ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/"> Home </a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact </a></li>
    <li><a href="">Help </a></li>
    <li><a href="">Support </a></li>
    <li><a href="">FAQ </a></li>
    <li><a href="">Hello </a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
<div class="btns12">
<h1>WE OWN THE STREETS</h1>
<div class ="button">
<a href= "http://www.google.com" class= "btn btn1"> Register Now </a>&nbsp;

<a href ="https://www.cairorunners.com/" class= "btn btn2"> Watch Video </a>
</div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to make a border appear whenever i hover over one of the elements of the list. However only the last 3 elements work. However, `Home` `Contact` `Help` are not working

here is the html

```
  <div class="menu">
<ul class="tabs">
<li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/"> Home </a></li>
<li><a href="">Contact </a></li>
<li><a href="">Help</a></li>
<li><a href="">Support </a></li>
<li><a href="">FAQ </a></li>
<li><a href="">Hello </a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and here is the css for the elements of the list

```
       .tabs{
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 30px;
    }
    .tabs li{
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .tabs li a{
      color: white;
      font-family: inherit;
       padding: 5px 30px;
       text-decoration: none;
       background: pink;
       height: 100%;
    }
     .tabs li a:hover{
      border:1px solid white;
    }
```

here is the whole css code:

```
    body{
  background: url("Mypic.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.btns12{
position: absolute;
width: 1200px;
margin-left:0px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 0px;
}
h1{
  color:gray;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 70px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-top: 450px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 250px;
}

.button{

  margin-left: 500px;
}

.btn{
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: pink;
 font-family: inherit;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.btn1:hover{
  background:white;
}
.btn2:hover{
    background:white;
}
.tabs{
float: right;
list-style: none;
margin-top: 30px;
}
.tabs li{
  display: inline-block;
}
.tabs li a{
  color: white;
  font-family: inherit;
   padding: 5px 30px;
   text-decoration: none;
   background: pink;
   height: 100%;
}
 .tabs li a:hover{
  border:1px solid white;
}
```

and here is the full html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Marwa's Services</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="menu">
    <ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/"> Home </a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact </a></li>
    <li><a href="">Help </a></li>
    <li><a href="">Support </a></li>
    <li><a href="">FAQ </a></li>
    <li><a href="">Hello </a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
<div class="btns12">
<h1>WE OWN THE STREETS</h1>
<div class ="button">
<a href= "http://www.google.com" class= "btn btn1"> Register Now </a>&nbsp;

<a href ="https://www.cairorunners.com/" class= "btn btn2"> Watch Video </a>
</div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: nothing seem to be issue in your code, its working perfectly fine when I tested.

Comment: @AryanTwanju i added my full css and html code can you please, rereview my question?

Comment: Just Changed the colors so you can see clearly [tested link](https://jsfiddle.net/Lt17n2xv/)

Comment: It's still working perfectly for me

Comment: @AnkitSingh when i add the full html code it stops working [testedlink2](https://jsfiddle.net/Lt17n2xv/4/)

Comment: @K.P. can you please check the link i posted in the comment above

Comment: why are you using things like position: absolute? I seems that it's not necessary at all and it's what's making your .btns12 overlay your buttons and make them under a div - therefore you can't cover them

Comment: the problem was in `absolute` but try to use `initial` instead
[Updated Link](https://jsfiddle.net/Lt17n2xv/7/)

Comment: @MarwaA. I have added my answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

You add this css

```
.btns12{
position: absolute;
width: 1200px;
margin-left:0px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 0px;
top:70px;
}
```

is overriding to your menu,so add `top:70px;` and check

```css
  body{
  background: url("Mypic.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.btns12{
position: absolute;
width: 1200px;
margin-left:0px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 0px;
top:70px;
}
h1{
  color:gray;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 70px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-top: 450px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 250px;
}

.button{

  margin-left: 500px;
}

.btn{
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: pink;
 font-family: inherit;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.btn1:hover{
  background:white;
}
.btn2:hover{
    background:white;
}
.tabs{
float: right;
list-style: none;
margin-top: 30px;
}
.tabs li{
  display: inline-block;
}
.tabs li a{
  color: white;
  font-family: inherit;
   padding: 5px 30px;
   text-decoration: none;
   background: pink;
   height: 100%;
}
 .tabs li a:hover{
  border:1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
    <ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/"> Home </a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact </a></li>
    <li><a href="">Help </a></li>
    <li><a href="">Support </a></li>
    <li><a href="">FAQ </a></li>
    <li><a href="">Hello </a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
<div class="btns12">
<h1>WE OWN THE STREETS</h1>
<div class ="button">
<a href= "http://www.google.com" class= "btn btn1"> Register Now </a>&nbsp;

<a href ="https://www.cairorunners.com/" class= "btn btn2"> Watch Video </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked. But can you please explain to how top solved the issue? How did that stop the process of overriding

Comment: give this css .menu{  position:relative;
   z-index:1} , without use top 70 px

Comment: Beacuse div start from top:0px , so by adding 70px it is start from 70px from top so it will not override menu

Answer (score 0):

Add this css rule to class .tabs

```
.tabs {

    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;

}
```

Comment: you applied css rule position absolute to your class .btns12. because of this menu div is placed behind this . inorder to access menu div you need to put z-index value greater than .btns12 to class .tabs

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  background: url("http://www.wallpapers4u.org/wp-content/uploads/patterns_background_dark_texture_50408_1920x1080-450x253.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.btns12 {
  position: initial;
  width: 1200px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

h1 {
  color: gray;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 70px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-top: 450px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 250px;
}

.button {
  margin-left: 500px;
}

.btn {
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: pink;
  font-family: inherit;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.btn1:hover {
  background: white;
}

.btn2:hover {
  background: white;
}

.tabs {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.tabs li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.tabs li a {
  color: white;
  font-family: inherit;
  padding: 5px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: pink;
  height: 100%;
}

.tabs li a:hover {
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Marwa's Services</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/"> Home </a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact </a></li>
      <li><a href="">Help </a></li>
      <li><a href="">Support </a></li>
      <li><a href="">FAQ </a></li>
      <li><a href="">Hello </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="btns12">
    <h1>WE OWN THE STREETS</h1>
    <div class="button">
      <a href="http://www.google.com" class="btn btn1"> Register Now </a>&nbsp;

      <a href="https://www.cairorunners.com/" class="btn btn2"> Watch Video </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
.menu {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
}
```

and delete `float: right` from .tabs

Answer (score 0):

Add attribute in your style may it help you....

```
  .tabs{
     z-index: 1;
     position: relative;
    }
    .tabs li a{
        border:1px solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hers I have edited your code to make it working. Try this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Marwa's Services</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="menu">
      <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/"> Home </a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact </a></li>
        <li><a href="">Help </a></li>
        <li><a href="">Support </a></li>
        <li><a href="">FAQ </a></li>
        <li><a href="">Hello </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="btns12">
      <h1>WE OWN THE STREETS</h1>
      <div class="button">
        <a href="http://www.google.com" class="btn btn1"> Register Now </a>&nbsp;

        <a href="https://www.cairorunners.com/" class="btn btn2"> Watch Video </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

And CSS,

```
body {
  background: url("Mypic.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.btns12 {}

h1 {
  color: gray;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 70px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  text-align: center;
}

.btn {
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: pink;
  font-family: inherit;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.btn1:hover {
  background: white;
}

.btn2:hover {
  background: white;
}

.tabs {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.tabs li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.tabs li a {
  color: white;
  font-family: inherit;
  padding: 5px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: pink;
  height: 100%;
}

.tabs li a:hover {
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set `overflow: hidden` to `.menu`

```css
body{
  background: url("Mypic.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.btns12{
position: absolute;
width: 1200px;
margin-left:0px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 0px;
}
h1{
  color:gray;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 70px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-top: 450px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 250px;
}

.button{

  margin-left: 500px;
}

.btn{
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: pink;
 font-family: inherit;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.btn1:hover{
  background:white;
}
.btn2:hover{
    background:white;
}
.tabs{
float: right;
list-style: none;
margin-top: 30px;
}
.tabs li{
  display: inline-block;
}
.tabs li a{
  color: white;
  font-family: inherit;
   padding: 5px 30px;
   text-decoration: none;
   background: pink;
   height: 100%;
}
 .tabs li a:hover{
  border:1px solid white;
}
.menu {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Marwa's Services</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="menu">
    <ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/"> Home </a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact </a></li>
    <li><a href="">Help </a></li>
    <li><a href="">Support </a></li>
    <li><a href="">FAQ </a></li>
    <li><a href="">Hello </a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
<div class="btns12">
<h1>WE OWN THE STREETS</h1>
<div class ="button">
<a href= "http://www.google.com" class= "btn btn1"> Register Now </a>&nbsp;

<a href ="https://www.cairorunners.com/" class= "btn btn2"> Watch Video </a>
</div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```